# Trying to edit Oslo masterpage to be full width and full height

Tags: oslo

I am trying to edit the Oslo masterpage so that it is full screen and full width.

I have managed to get the full width element working but now I am stuck with the height of the page. I have attached an image to better show my issue but it appears that I am getting about 50px of padding at the bottom and top of the page. Can anyone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding-bottom style property for the `s4-bodyContainer` div

```
#s4-bodyContainer{
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

If it gets overridden due to any other style apply `!important` to the set value.